# How to get graphically connected array items in Python?

Tags: python

Alright... Here's a fun question.
I want to make a program that counts how many patches are connected in a string.
To make this a little easier to grasp, here is how the input/outputs should go:

Input:

```
.....%%%%%..%
%%%...%%...%%
%.....%%%..%%
...%%.....%%%
....%%.....%%
.....%%%..%%%
%%%%....%%%..
```

Output:
4 patches.

One block of paint is a "%" sign and a empty space is a ".".
How would I go about finding the number of patches?

For instance, a connected patch would be a few % signs connected like this:

```
%%%%%
%%...
%....
```

Comment: Why doesn't your raster have 5 "patches"? ... or is diagonal proximity considered connected?

Comment: Diagonal proximity is indeed considered.

Comment: you may need to use for loop to start with every place and run recursion to check if there is connected element in all directions. And when you get all pathes then you can use `len()`

Comment: Unfortunately for my problem I cannot use recursion since the strings will take far too long due to their size.

Comment: What is the "real" string size?

Comment: Can be a random string size. The string is inputted in through the input() function. It can be of any random size that the user wishes.

Comment: It is the width of the string inputted * height of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it by using a bit of hackery to create a [`NetworkX Graph`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/graph.html) and then just using [`NetworkX` algorithm `number_connected_components`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.number_connected_components.html).

```py
$ ipython
Python 3.10.6 (main, Aug  2 2022, 00:00:00) [GCC 11.3.1 20220421 (Red Hat 11.3.1-2)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 8.4.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: raster='''.....%%%%%..%
   ...: %%%...%%...%%
   ...: %.....%%%..%%
   ...: ...%%.....%%%
   ...: ....%%.....%%
   ...: .....%%%..%%%
   ...: %%%%....%%%..'''

In [2]: import networkx as nx

In [3]: vertices = [(row, column) for row,line in enumerate(raster.splitlines()) for column,char in
   ...: enumerate(line) if char=='%']

In [4]: G = nx.Graph()

In [5]: G.add_nodes_from(vertices)

In [6]: for node in G:
   ...:     for x in range(node[0]-1,node[0]+2):
   ...:         for y in range (node[1]-1,node[1]+2):
   ...:             if (x,y) in G:
   ...:                 G.add_edge(node, (x,y))
   ...: 

In [7]: nx.number_connected_components(G)
Out[7]: 4
```

If for some unfortunate reason, nice libraries/packages (like `NetworkX`) can't be used, here's another way to do it.

```py
$ ipython
Python 3.10.6 (main, Aug  2 2022, 00:00:00) [GCC 11.3.1 20220421 (Red Hat 11.3.1-2)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 8.4.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: raster='''.....%%%%%..%
   ...: %%%...%%...%%
   ...: %.....%%%..%%
   ...: ...%%.....%%%
   ...: ....%%.....%%
   ...: .....%%%..%%%
   ...: %%%%....%%%..'''

In [2]: vertices = [(row, column) for row,line in enumerate(raster.splitlines()) for column,char in
   ...: enumerate(line) if char=='%']

In [3]: vertex_edges = dict()

In [4]: for vertex in vertices:
   ...:     vertex_edges[vertex] = set()
   ...:     for x in range(vertex[0]-1, vertex[0]+2):
   ...:         for y in range (vertex[1]-1, vertex[1]+2):
   ...:             if ((x,y) != vertex) and ((x,y) in vertices):
   ...:                 vertex_edges[vertex].add((x,y))
   ...: 

In [5]: num_connected_components = 0

In [6]: removed_vertices = set()

In [7]: while len(vertex_edges) > 0:
   ...:     num_connected_components += 1
   ...:     vertex, vertex_set = vertex_edges.popitem()
   ...:     removed_vertices.add(vertex)
   ...:     while len(vertex_set) > 0:
   ...:         vertex = vertex_set.pop()
   ...:         if vertex in vertex_edges:
   ...:             removed_vertices.add(vertex)
   ...:             vertex_set = vertex_set.union(vertex_edges[vertex] - removed_vertices)
   ...:             _ = vertex_edges.pop(vertex)
   ...: 

In [8]: num_connected_components
Out[8]: 4
```

Comment: Well the problem is... I can't use networkx.

Comment: @LashenDharmadasa Perhaps you can get some ideas from the [source code](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/_modules/networkx/algorithms/components/connected.html#number_connected_components).

Comment: I do not get it, the source code is kind of hard to understand and since I am not allowed to use any libraries, I would have to write the entire library down in one file...

Comment: @LashenDharmadasa I added a library/package-free method to the answer.  I didn't extensively test it so YMMV.  If you find that it works, or doesn't work, please let me know.

Comment: It works, sorry for the late reply!